# It is possible to remove user message from Facebook Bot chat?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, x-facebook-platform

I need some feature to remove user input message from conversation with my facebook bot.

I need to make authorization routine with my server application, because it working with private user information.

Therefore I want to make prompt of user password and of course it must be removed from the chat or replaced with ******.

How to handle this kind of scenario via Facebook Bot Chat ?
If it impossible, can anyone suggest me a workaround to this problem ?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a way to delete a message / conversation from Facebook bot chat via Facebook apis but was not able to find a way or a specific api to delete message / conversation.

However for this particular scenario Facebook has given a way to authenticate a user with our own system with. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking

So you could use this to authenticate a user with your system with login process and unauthenticated with logout process.

Hope this helps for others who has similar thoughts.